# Creating a Tree Style-List with JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a javascript function that creates `<ul>` elements for each index in an array that is created from a MySqli query done in PHP.

What I want to do is allow a user to click each `<ul>` element to reveal their child `<ul>` (which can also be used to reveal children) or `<li>` elements (which can be clicked to call a function).

```
HTML, JS, PHP:

<div id ="fileTreeContainer"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

<?php
$genre_query = "SELECT DISTINCT genre FROM songs ORDER BY genre ASC;";
$genre_result = $connect -> query($genre_query);
$genre_row = $genre_result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
$genre_array = json_encode($genre_row);

echo "var genreArray = " . $genre_array . ";";
?>

function genreList(item) {
  $("#fileTreeContainer").append("<ul class=\"genre\">" + item + "<li class=\"hidden\">\"artist\">jfkjfk</li></ul>");
}

genreArray.forEach(genreList);

</script>
```

```
CSS:

.hidden { display: none; }
```

I've tried using a number of libraries designed to create tree-style menus like this but I haven't been able to get anything to work.

I'm using `$('.genre').click( function() { $('.hidden', this).toggle(); } );` to hide/reveal the child element but this does not allow for the child element to be clicked.

I also have React included but I'm still not familiar with it.

Could someone help me out? I've been browsing existing questions and trying solutions all day to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using nested `<details><summary` elements like this:

```
<details><summary>summary1</summary>

  <details><summary>summary2</summary>
    
    <details><summary>summary3</summary>
      <p>content1</p>
    </details>

    <p>content2</p>
    <p>content3</p>

  </details>

  <details><summary>summary4</summary>
    <p>content5</p>
    <p>content6</p>
  </details>

</details>
```

While still using jquery to create the elements.